# Asynchronous requests from Play(2.0) Action to Akka Actor

Tags: akka, playframework-2.0

We just start testing Play!Framework and akka, for use it in our
future projects.

1. We would like to know how to make an asynchronous call from an
   Action in the Controller of PLAY![2.0] to an Actor in Akka. We have
   seen examples in the scala API but no examples in java API.
2. To make asynchronous requests, we believe that we must to use the
   class play.libs.WS and play.libs.F.Promise but these do not appear in
   play_2.9.1.jar they only appear in the API (https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/libs)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing things a little up.

play.libs.WS is for webservice requests (requests to certain urls). 
play.libs.F.Promise is (afaik) just a relict from Play 1.x

To use a actor, instantiate a ActorSystem, then create a actor
and send a message to him. If you "ask" ( actor.ask(...) ) for a result, 
you can use Await.(don't know the exact name right now, use source completion of your IDE) to wait for its response.